# Using a special key in function

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to remap `<PageUp>` key to call this function:

```
function! PageUp()
    let l:line = line('.')
    if(l:line != 1)
        if(l:line != winline())
            :set syntax=off
            <PageUp>
            :set syntax=on
        else
            normal! 1G
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

but gvim complains that I cannot do it.

So what is the proper way to use the keys in a function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you use the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> key in Normal mode so the underlying functionality is a Normal mode command. You can't use such commands directly while in an Ex command-line or function/script. You need to use the Ex command [`:norm`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:norm) for this.

Further, to use "key codes" ([`:h key-codes`](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#keycodes)) of non-printing characters like `<PageUp>` you need to construct the `:norm` command as an [*expression*](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#eval) and pass it to the [`:exe`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#:exe) command (see last paragraph of [`:h :norm`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:norm)).

That gives us:

```
:exe "norm \<PageUp>"
```

The double quotes are required as is the `\` to escape the keycode and indicate that you want the special meaning not the literal string "<PageUp>".

(Note: Usually we want to use `norm!` instead of `norm` in order to avoid conflicts with mappings but that's not a critical element of this answer so omitted.)

Comment: The doc on escaping special keys using ``\`` is on `:h expr-quote`.

Answer (score 1):

To send special key to `:normal`, you need to get it's raw code by using `"\<key>"` notation.

```
exec "norm! \<PageUp>"
```

You can also use raw code directly if you want(not recommended, hard to read):

```
norm! <80>kP
        ^----------<80> is 0x80
```

`<80>kP` is raw code of `<PageUp>`, you can enter it like this in normal mode:

```
"="\<PageUp>"<cr>p
              ^----------press carriage return
```

If raw code of the key doesn't start with `0x80`, it's the same as terminal code (not sure), you can use the `:h i_CTRL-V` to insert terminal code:

```
norm! <c-v><c-p>
       ^------------press ctrl-v ctrl-p
```

- `:h :exec`
- `:h quote=`
- `:h string`